# Multiple Lines in NSTextFieldCell

Tags: nstextfieldcell, nstableviewcell

How can I have multiple lines in my NSTextFieldCell in my NSTableView?  By this I mean have multiple lines of data:

Ex

`Stack Overflow www.stackoverflow.com`

turns into this:

```
Stack Overflow

www.stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Parts of the solution would involve telling the cell that the text can wrap, and telling the table that the row heights vary.  Getting the details right seems to be a tricky problem, or at least it was in 2005 when [this discussion](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/139642-nstableview-row-height-calculation.html) was written.